# Better understanding of Sonicwall VPN DNS and NETBIOS required

Tags: networking, dns, firewall, radius

I would be interested in hearing from anyone that has successfully established a VPN connection through a Sonicwall (TZ-100) device on to a SBS-2008 network as I currently have VPN access (through the Sonicwall Global VPN Client), but I am currently using a local user account from the firewall device.

As I am not establishing the VPN request using my Windows-AD username and password, I am having to enter my windows credentials to access network resources. Launching Outlook does not show my mail (even if I type in my password when promted). If I type in \\MyServerName\SharedFolder into Explorer, then I see the 'offline' sync folders stored on my laptop. On the otherhand, if I type \\192.168.100.10\SharedFolder (lets assume this is the LAN IP4 address for my server), then once I enter my windows credentials, I can see ALL the 'online' folders. Currently, for mail, I am using OWA while connected on the VPN. This current approach is not ideal. I feel there is a DNS, NETBIOS problem with my current set up.

Question, so that I can work from home in a 'normal uninterrupted' manner, do I need to activate 1. Radius by itself?, 2. LDAP by itself? or 3. Radius + LDAP together? Any pointers would be helpful as I would like to approach the Sonicwall support team armed with a little more info and having read some friendly material.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by changing the DNS address on the Sonicwall device to the server rather than inherritting the external DNS addresses from the ISP. Also the DHCP service was routed to the server for VPN traffic.

There is no need to set up any additional services on the server to get LDAP running on the Sonicwall device. With a little help from the Sonicwall support, my network now works as one would expect.